# Set app.config parameters from a Visual Studio 2008 Setup project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I have a WinForms application that uses a config file to specify where it's external files will be created.

Is it possible to use the installer to question the user where the files should be located and  add this value to the config file?

It would also be good if I could confirm that the user has entered a valid path but that's just a "Nice-to-have" at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the helpful hints from **Pete**, I was able to find [this blog](http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/) that does exactly what I need.

There are a few Gotchas to watch out for and I've covered them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491095/error-11001-using-custom-installer-with-visual-studio-2008) but these may be Visual Studio 2008 specific issues.

Comment: I think the link is dead.